# Detect repeated text

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot using node.js and I wanted to add an anti spam feature to it. The goal is simple:

I would like to match, using regex preferably, the following sentence:

`hello my name is anon hello my name is anon hello my name is anon hello my name is anon`

Tho, I dont want it to match these strings:

`hello my name is anon hello my name is anon hello my name is anon`

`hello my name is anon`

`hello, my name is anon hello my name is anon hello my name is anon hello my name is anon`
(notice the comma at the start)

Of course, the few words im using here could be anything and thats were I need your help... Is regex able to do this? If so, how? I took a look at words boundaries and stuff but im pretty lost here...

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need to state the rule you are using to determine whether a string is to match, as it is not obvious from the examples. I made an assumption in my answer but cannot be sure it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to identify strings of the form `s s s sx`, where `s` is a common substring and `x` is any substring, you could use the regular expression

```
^(.+)(?: +\1){3}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v4FGgA/3/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^            match beginning of line
(.*+)        match any char other than newline, 1+ times,
             saving to capture group 1
(?: +\1)     match 1+ spaces followed by the content of
             capture group 1 in a non-cap group
{3}          execute non-cap group 3 times
```

Comment: Exacly what I needed. Thanks alot for the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

This problem reduces to finding a non-empty sequence, such that repeated x times equals the whole string.

I suggest a possible solution:

```js
function checkRep(str){
  return /^(.+?)\1+$/.test(str);
}

console.log(checkRep("example")); // false
console.log(checkRep("example example")); // false
console.log(checkRep("example example ")); // true
console.log(checkRep("example example hello")); // false
```

Notice that `\1` is just a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the match `(.+?)`.

And in case you do not want to take whitespaces into account (recommended), you can use:

```js
function checkRep(str){
  return /^\s*(.+?)(\s*\1\s*)+$/.test(str);
}

console.log(checkRep("example")); // false
console.log(checkRep("example example")); // true
console.log(checkRep("example example ")); // true
console.log(checkRep("example example hello")); // false
```